# Update list item

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-online, document-template, update

I've developed an app which stores some data in a list. This triggers a workflow that makes a word document in a separate document library in the same site collection. All works fine so far. The problems start when I want to update the document.

I've created a workflow that updates items from the list to the document library. I've also created a column in the document library that stores the ID from the first list. I've set field to the ID in the document library and value to the ID in the list the workflow is triggered on. It's triggered on a change in an item. This workflow fails every time. I suspect that it might be because there's over 5000 items in the document library, so it can't be indexed.

I should mention that this is a 2010 workflow.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to solve this?
My experience with workflows is limited, so any input would be greatly apreceated.

Comment: What is the error message that you get? Can you check the workflow history?

Comment: Unfortunately not a spesific one. "An error has occured in WF_updatedoc."

Comment: Was the workflow running on document update before you hit 5000 items in the library?

Comment: There was 5000 items there before I made it, but a co-worker suspected that it might be the problem.

Comment: Your best bet would be to replicate this in a fresh list so that you can zero in on the cause.

Comment: Seems to work on a fresh list. Any ideas on how to work around this 5000 limit?

Comment: A better workaround would be to try writing event receivers for this as you have little control over how workflows operate. In code, you have much more freedom.

Comment: That is true. But I've only done those in C#. This is a pure JS SharePoint hosted app.

Answer (score 0):

Okey so I did a workaround. First i put the ID from the list into the document column on item created. Then I used a workflow to trigger on change in the document library, which checked two columns: fromApp and isSet. If both are true, it sets its own ID to the correct item in the first list, and changes isSet to true.

Then, through code in the app, I set a column in the list to true if the app is changing something rather than creating, so that the workflow in the document library doesn't trigger the update workflow in the list *(sorry, don't know how to write this in a tidy way)*. Only when that field is true, the update workflow for the document triggers.

Hope this might help people in a similar situations one day.